# Reading data from azure blob storage without Sas token and master key in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

How we can read data from Azure blob storage without using SAS token and master key? If the user already has some role like Contributor or Reader of storage account or container.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to use either SAS token or account key, you can leverage AAD authentication by assigning any of the following RBAC roles to your spark.

**Storage Blob Data Owner**: Use to set ownership and manage POSIX access control for Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. For more information, see Access control in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2.

**Storage Blob Data Contributor**: Use to grant read/write/delete permissions to Blob storage resources.

**Storage Blob Data Reader**: Use to grant read-only permissions to Blob storage resources.

**Storage Blob Delegator**: Get a user delegation key to use to create a shared access signature that is signed with Azure AD credentials for a container or blob.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory#azure-built-in-roles-for-blobs

Comment: thanks for your reply .Can we use user permission to generate sas token  ? I am able to generate sas token by registering app and grant read-write permission to that application.